# Generating API client libraries using swagger codegen plugin with Python

Tags: python-3.x, swagger-codegen

I used swagger codegen plugin with gradle for generating API client libraries from the json. For Gradle I followed the steps from [here](https://github.com/thebignet/swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin-example) and it worked perfectly fine. For Python since there is no gradle.build or pom.xml file I am not able to generate client libraries and I am a Python beginner. Also one thing to add is that I am not creating any APIs, I just want to extract API client libraries from the json file that I have.

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a Python client from an OpenAPI definition? Or do you mean "how to run Swagger Codegen from Python"?

Comment: Yes Helen, I want to generate OpenAPI definition. For Gradle I created a task in build.gradle, you can check the link above for what I did with gradle.